# Generating both APK and play store submission with only one build process in Expo EAS

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play, eas

I have an app built in React Native with Expo which currently uses Expo's EAS cloud to build new versions of the app and submit the aab to Google Play store.
However, we started to also have the need of publishing the app's APK file as a GitHub release artifact.
Currently we achieved that by configurating different eas profiles in eas.json and running in our CI one command to build the APK and another to build the AAB and submit to google play.

The problem with that is the fact that two build processes need to happen, which means more infrastructure time and costs.

So I was wondering if there exists any alternative approach, to build only once and have both the APK and the Play Store submission. Or is building twice the standard approach in these cases?

Thank you!